# How can I segregate the csv file data and write it to different files?

Tags: integration, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

My input is a csv file containing below data

```
ID,Name,ContactNo,CompName,Department
101,Angel,0000000000,XYZ Org,HR
102,Melinda,0000000000,XYZ Org,Accounts
103,Jack,0000000000,XYZ Org,HR
104,Ron,0000000000,XYZ Org,HR
105,Marie,0000000000,XYZ Org,Accounts
106,Eva,0000000000,XYZ Org,Sales
107,Nate,0000000000,XYZ Org,Sales
```

Based on the Department name I want to write the records to different files like below

*HR File*

```
101,Angel,0000000000,XYZ Org,HR
103,Jack,0000000000,XYZ Org,HR
104,Ron,0000000000,XYZ Org,HR
```

*Accounts File*

```
102,Melinda,0000000000,XYZ Org,Accounts
105,Marie,0000000000,XYZ Org,Accounts
```

How can I segregate the data based on the Department name and write it to different files?

Comment: Please use multiline code format (three backticks in a single line `````) for text data, code and logs.

Answer (score 2):

Use groupBy() to group by department, then pluck() to convert to an array that is easy to iterate in a foreach scope where you can write each file.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload groupBy($.Department) pluck {department:$$, records:$}
```

The output is an array of objects. Each object has a `department` key that you can use to set the name of the output CSV file and a `records` key which is an array of the records that match that department.

Output (as JSON for clarity, should be Java)

```js
[
  {
    "department": "HR ",
    "records": [
      {
        "ID": "101",
        "Name": "Angel",
        "ContactNo": "0000000000",
        "CompName": "XYZ Org",
        "Department": "HR "
      },
      {
        "ID": "104",
        "Name": "Ron",
        "ContactNo": "0000000000",
        "CompName": "XYZ Org",
        "Department": "HR "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "department": "Accounts ",
    "records": [
      {
        "ID": "102",
        "Name": "Melinda",
        "ContactNo": "0000000000",
        "CompName": "XYZ Org",
        "Department": "Accounts "
      },
      {
        "ID": "105",
        "Name": "Marie",
        "ContactNo": "0000000000",
        "CompName": "XYZ Org",
        "Department": "Accounts "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "department": "HR",
    "records": [
      {
        "ID": "103",
        "Name": "Jack",
        "ContactNo": "0000000000",
        "CompName": "XYZ Org",
        "Department": "HR"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "department": "Sales",
    "records": [
      {
        "ID": "106",
        "Name": "Eva",
        "ContactNo": "0000000000",
        "CompName": "XYZ Org",
        "Department": "Sales"
      },
      {
        "ID": "107",
        "Name": "Nate",
        "ContactNo": "0000000000",
        "CompName": "XYZ Org",
        "Department": "Sales"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Inside a foreach `payload.records` gives you the array of records to convert to CSV that you will write to each file.

```xml
<foreach>
   ...
   %dw 2.0
   output application/csv
   ---
   payload.records
   ...
</foreach>
```

Comment: I've followed what you suggested and using below code to write it as a csv                   %dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload map {
 ID: $.records.ID,
 Name:  $.records.Name,
 ContactNo:  $.records.ContactNo,
 CompName:  $.records.CompName,
 Department:  $.records.Department
}

Comment: its giving me below error message Expecting Type: `Array<T>`, but got: `{|CarProvider: Number,
   records: String|}`.
 |-- From: `Array<T>`
 |---- From: map(items:
   `Array<T>`, mapper: (item: `T`, index: `Number`) -> `R`) ->
   `Array<R>`

Comment: 1) you are using an incorrect transformation and/or doing it in the wrong place. `$.records.id` doesn't make sense for the output I shared. Anyway I expanded my answer so please read and try again. 2) `CarProvider` doesn't exist in your question. If you are doing something different to what was stated in the question you should edit your question and clarify it.